# Creating a PDF with table having dynamic rows in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make a dynamic table with list contents. I am not able to map the array list with the List type of table data. I am not getting table in PDF and instead it's showing me an error.

This is my PDF code:

```
   goTocreatePdf(context,AllTranList) async {
   final Document pdf = Document();

    pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
    pageFormat:
    PdfPageFormat.letter.copyWith(marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    header: (Context context) {
    if (context.pageNumber == 1) {
      return null;
    }
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border:
            BoxBorder(bottom: true, width: 0.5, color: PdfColors.grey)),
        child: Text('Report',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .defaultTextStyle
                .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
  },
  footer: (Context context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        child: Text('Page ${context.pageNumber} of ${context.pagesCount}',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .defaultTextStyle
                .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
  },
  build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
    Header(
        level: 0,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('TRANSACTION LIST', textScaleFactor: 2),
              PdfLogo()
            ])),
    Header(level: 1, text: 'What is Lorem Ipsum?'),

            Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data:  <List<String>>[
        <String>[ 'TRANSACTION_AMOUNT No', 'CUSTREF_ID', 
  'REMARKS','PAYEE_VIR_ID','PAYER_VIR_ID'],
  ...AllTranList.map(
          (item) => [item.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
       item.CUSTREF_ID,item.REMARKS,item.PAYEE_VIR_ID,item.PAYER_VIR_ID])
        ]),

       //save PDF
       final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
       final String path = '$dir/report.pdf';
       Dio dio = new Dio();
       final File file = File(path);
       await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
       material.Navigator.of(context).push(
       material.MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (_) => PdfViewerPage(path: path),
     ),
    );
  }
```

Also I am not able to save PDF in the external storage.

This is the AllTransitList that I am mapping:

> ```
> [{TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: 1.00,
>   CUSTREF_ID: 001819655570,
>   CREATED_ON: 2020-01-18T19:55:40.412Z,
>   REMARKS: SUCCESS,
>   RESPONSE: SUCCESS,
>   PAYEE_VIR_ID: navyabj@fbl,
>   PAYER_VIR_ID: abinthomas0073@oksbi},
>  {TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: 1.00,
>   CUSTREF_ID: 002218989414,
>   CREATED_ON: 2020-01-22T18:12:13.500Z,
>   REMARKS: SUCCESS,
>   RESPONSE: SUCCESS,
>   PAYEE_VIR_ID: navyabj@fbl,
>   PAYER_VIR_ID: abinthomas0073@oksbi},
>  {TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: 30.00,
>   CUSTREF_ID: 002218162602,
>   CREATED_ON: 2020-01-22T18:13:12.835Z,
>   REMARKS: SUCCESS,
>   RESPONSE: SUCCESS,
>   PAYEE_VIR_ID: navyabj@fbl,
>   PAYER_VIR_ID: aju@federal},
>  {TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: 36.00,
>   CUSTREF_ID: 002219179966,
>   CREATED_ON: 2020-01-22T19:23:21.377Z,
>   REMARKS: SUCCESS,
>   RESPONSE: SUCCESS,
>   PAYEE_VIR_ID: navyabj@fbl,
>   PAYER_VIR_ID: aju@federal}]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this library.

you can create pdf with this library :

https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

i hope it's useful